# Как запретить индексировать уровни вложенности ссылок в robots или htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, индексация, robots.txt

Всем привет!

Есть сайт у которого все актуальные ссылки имеют примерно такой вид https://teplo-garant.com/zip, т.е. https://домен/контентнаястраница.

Но в индекс залезли такие ссылки типа https://teplo-garant.com/zip/blablabla, т.е. https://домен/контентнаястраница/икакаятоерунда.

Кто-нибудь знает, как в robots или может htaccess запретить индексировать всё что идёт после /zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

запрещается таким образом:

```
Disallow: /zip/*
```